# iTunes randomly thinking my iPhone/iPad is "new"

Tags: itunes

One of the extremely irritating things that (the Windows version of) iTunes does is that from time to time when I connect my previously-set-up iPhone or iPad, it thinks that it is a "new" device. Thus when I connect, it takes me to the "Set Up Your iPhone" screen and insists that I either "Set up as a new iPhone" or "Restore from a backup", despite the fact that neither is it a new device nor do I wish to restore from any backup and the thing I want to do is just "do nothing" and carry on as before...

Am I the only person in the universe to have this problem, and if not, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: It sounds like it's probably an iPhone software issue, have you tried restoring it as a new device to see if the problem persists?

Comment: Every time the above happens, I say that it's a "new device". Then for a while things are fine, then at some random point, it happens again.

Answer (score 1):

Completely restore the iPhone using DFU mode.

See the instructions posted on [this website](http://thebigboss.org/guides-iphone-ipod-ipad/dfu-mode) and then do a complete restore of your iPhone and set it up as new.

If the problem persists, it might be that your iTunes would need to be reinstalled. Don't forget to unlink your library to your computer before uninstalling iTunes and keep a copy of your data.

Consolidate your library PRIOR to backing it up, removing iTunes, etc., etc.